# How do I enable the SSE3/SSE4.1 instruction set in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sse, simd, sse3

I tried to follow:

Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation > Enable Enhanced Instruction Set

But the only options I got were - SSE or SSE2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're serious about using SSE then ditch the Microsoft compiler and use a decent compiler. Intel's ICC is probably the best bet. It has full support for SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4.1, SSE4.2 and generates much better code.

Comment: Please keep in mind with ICC that Intel may have crippled performance on non-Intel CPUs.  See here for more details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_C%2B%2B_Compiler#Criticism

Comment: I *think* that's out of date as of ICC 11 and 12 ?

Comment: While still seemingly present with a default configuration, I found a reference guide by AMD for ICC 12 for optimal performance: http://developer.amd.com/Assets/CompilerOptQuickRef-61004100.pdf

Answer (score -3):

[Let me google that for you](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=iGR&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=sse4+visual+studio+2008&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)

First two links seem to answer your question. SSE3 and SSE4 are not going to be added. if you want to use then you can use intrinsic functions.

Comment: Times have changed, the first two results are (1) behind a login wall and (2) this page.